# Removing stop words with tidytext

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidytext

Using tidytext, I have this code:

```
data(stop_words)
tidy_documents <- tidy_documents %>%
      anti_join(stop_words)
```

I want it to use the stop words built into the package to write a dataframe called tidy_documents into a dataframe of the same name, but with the words removed if they are in stop_words.

I get this error:

Error: No common variables. Please specify `by` param.
Traceback:

```
1. tidy_documents %>% anti_join(stop_words)
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(expr, envir, enclos)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
8. function_list[[k]](value)
9. anti_join(., stop_words)
10. anti_join.tbl_df(., stop_words)
11. common_by(by, x, y)
12. stop("No common variables. Please specify `by` param.", call. = FALSE)
```

Comment: Clearly `tidy_documents` and `stop_words` don't share any variable names, so you'll need to match the two dataset using the `by` parameter.

Comment: The column of `stop_words` is called `word`, so either name your column that or use the `by` parameter of `anti_join`.

Comment: What are the column names in `tidy_documents`? We can tell you specifically how to set up the join if you share that.

Comment: @JuliaSilge Columns in `tidy_documents` are `author; date; word´.

Comment: @textnet Hmmmmm, that seems odd then. If you have a `word` column in your main dataset, I would expect `anti_join()` would know to match it up with the `word` column in the `stop_words` dataset. Can you try to [make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with data?

Comment: @JuliaSilge Thanks, but I think I got it to work. Like this `data(stop_words)
tidy_base <- anti_join(tidy_base, stop_words, by="word")`. Seems reasonable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both `tidy_document` and `stop_words` have a list of words listed under a column named `word`; however, the columns are inverted: in `stop_words`, it's the first column, while in your dataset it's the second column. That's why the command is unable to "match" the two columns and compare the words. Try this:

```
tidy_document <- tidy_document %>% 
      anti_join(stop_words, by = c("word" = "word"))
```

The `by` command forces the script to compare the columns that are called `word`, regardless their position.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the simpler `filter()` to avoid using the confusing `anti_join()` function like this:

```
tidy_documents <- tidy_documents %>%
  filter(!word %in% stop_words$word)
```